# Missing float function in awk on RHEL 5.8

Tags: rhel, awk

Why is `float` missing in `awk` on my RHEL 5.8?  Was it replaced by some other function?

On Solaris:

```
echo "Foampile=123" | awk -F"=" '{ print float($2) "<->" $1 }'
```

returns

```
123<->Foampile
```

on RHEL 5.8

```
awk: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: function `float' not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solaris `/usr/bin/awk` is a very old awk that doesn't support user functions. So in that awk, `float(123)` is the same as `anything(123)` or `anything 123`, that is the concatenation of the value of the `float` or `anything` variable (empty if not set) and `123`. So, it's not an error, but it does nothing.

Had you written

```
echo "Foampile=123" | awk -F '=' '{float="x"; print float($2) "<->" $1}'
```

you'd have seen

```
x123<->Foampile
```

I don't think that there is any awk implementation that has a `float` function.

What would you expect that function to do anyway?

On the other hand, modern POSIX awks like Solaris `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` or `nawk` or `gawk` do support user functions, so in those, unless you define the `float` or `anything` function, you'll see that error.

```
echo "Foampile=123" | awk -F '=' '{ print $2 "<->" $1 }'
```

would work exactly the same (and would work with modern awks).

In modern awks, to disambiguate between a function call and the concatenation of a variable and something within brace, you need to add at least one extra space:

```
$ echo x | awk '{print foo ($1)}'
x
$ echo x | awk 'function foo(x) {return "y"}; {print foo($1)}'
y
```

Comment: I am migrating some scripts (that I didn't write) from SunOS->RHEL.  My goal is to get the script to do the same thing as in the previous OS by evaluating ins and outs but not really diving into why things like `float` and such were used.  Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a Solaris specific function. You might need to instead use printf or sprintf and specify the float.

`awk 'BEGIN {printf "%1##f\n", "<->" $1}`

Comment: in Solaris i don't get an error.  in RHEL i do.

Comment: @foampile You need to replace "##" with real numbers.